# Puppet Exec what "<| |>" means?

Tags: puppet

I'm learning puppet language and noticed one very intriguing line of code: `Exec["apt-update"] -> Package <| |>` on following context:

```
class manifest::module {

  exec { "apt-update":
      command => "/usr/bin/apt-get -y update",
      timeout => 3600;
  }

  package {
    ["alien", "bc", "libaio1", "unixodbc", "unzip", "rlwrap"]:
      ensure => installed;
  }

  Exec["apt-update"] -> Package <| |>
}
```

Why Exec is followed by the `->`? And most important, what's the meaning of `<| |>` ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This expression essentially instructs Puppet to have any package resource require the "apt-update" exec resource. In other words Puppet will be sure to execute **apt-get update** before installing/purging/... a package.

Comment: It also have a side effect : it will realize ALL virtual resources of type `package`, as explained in [the reference](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/3/reference/lang_collectors.html#behavior)

Answer (score 1):

It matches any package, see http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_collectors.html for more details