# what does this Puppet code do: Homebrew::Formula <| |> -> Package <| |>

Tags: puppet, boxen

can someone please explain what this Puppet code means?

```
Homebrew::Formula <| |> -> Package <| |>
```

it can be found in the boxen/our-boxen [github repo](https://github.com/boxen/our-boxen/blob/master/manifests/site.pp#L52). i'm totally noob to Puppet (and Boxen). i've been reading another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20593368/puppet-exec-what-means) and what seems to be the [relevant Puppet docs](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/3/reference/lang_collectors.html), but Puppet has a *lot* of domain-specific concepts and operations, and i've yet to wrap my head around this one.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Resource::Type<| |>` syntax is indeed meant for the collection of virtual resources, e.g. you have one

```
@homebrew::formula { "mytitle": param => value, ... }
```

in the manifest at some point (maybe others with different resource titles) and all classes that want to make sure those are realized into actual resources, do a collection using either

```
Homebrew::Formula<| title == 'mytitle' |>
```

or

```
realize(homebrew[mytitle])
```

Note that `Homebrew::Formula <| |>` will realize **all** virtual resource.

A little known fact is that the same syntax can be used to do *overrides*, e.g.

```
Homebrew::Formula<| title == 'mytitle' |> { param => other_value }
```

even if the original resource was *not* virtual.

It is likely that the quoted statement is used as an override to state that `all homebrew::formula resources should be evaluated before any package resource`.

Comment: ok... so the first `<| |>` selects all the `Homebrew::Formula` resources, and the second `<| |>` selects all the `Package` resources. that was pretty much my guess. thanks for the help, Puppet has a mean learning curve. also, thanks for fixing the links, i don't have enough rep to be trusted linkin' ;)

Comment: Aight *boost* :-) Feel free to accept the answer if it was helpful *hint hint* ;)

Comment: hehe, i didn't even know that button was there. i tried to upvote it but i had too little rep. accepted.